# Bootable external hard drive via thunderbolt

Tags: dual-boot, raid, ubuntu-studio, thunderbolt

I am purchasing a high end computer (64GB Ram, 500Ghz, Raid0 SSDs) for my business.
I don't want to dual boot UbuntuStudio because I want to keep the windows Raid0 configuration, but I've considered running Ustudio from an external hard drive via the thunderbolt 3 connection.  Will this option give severely limited performance?  Will Ustudio be able to take advantage of the computer's performance capability, or will it just get bottled up by running off an external drive?

Comment: Is there another drive bay to put Drive 3 inside the chassis, or does the motherboard have an M.2 socket for a third drive? That would also eliminate an performance drawbacks.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion. I believe there is a socket for a third drive, and that may be the way to go. Thank you for the idea, I will look into the specs to be sure that it's doable. I'm still curious, though, what would the performance be like using an external hard drive via Thunderbolt. Anyone that has any thoughts on that, I would welcome the input.